# how to add ternary operator in navlink react?getting error that page not found this is the code that i'm using in header. how can i add this conditon

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
      <li className="nav-item dropdown">
  <NavLink className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  aria-expanded="false">
   {auth?.user?.name}
  </NavLink>
  <ul className="dropdown-menu " >
<li><NavLink to={'/dashboard/{JSON.stringify(auth,null,4)}'}  className="nav-link">Dashboard</NavLink></li>
  <li> <NavLink  to="/login" onClick={handleLogout} className="nav-link" >Logout</NavLink></li>
       <li><NavLink to={'/dashboard/${auth?.user?.role===1?"admin":"user"}'} className="nav-link">
       Dashboard
       </NavLink></li>   

  </ul>
</li>
```

getting error that page not found this is the code that i am using in header.js section  to get the user role. How can I fix this..
i want to add ternary operator in navlink to get the detail of user role if role is 1 go to get set as admin ..
but while testing i was getting   in url.

localhost:3000/dashboard/%7BJSON.stringify(auth,null,4)%7D

Comment: This is a typo. Change **to={'/dashboard/{JSON.stringify(auth,null,4)}'}** to **to={'/dashboard/${JSON.stringify(auth,null,4)}'}** . I added **$** for proper use of string interpolation

Comment: i don't this the problem is with the ternary operator, i this you are missong "$" befofe {JSON.stringify(auth,null,4)}, and dont forget use backticks instead of quotes, :
          `to={`/dashboard/${JSON.stringify(auth,null,4)}`}`